# Passing data and displaying on data grid with multiple stacks

Tags: datagrid, stack, livecode

I'm compiling a mobile app that combines multiple stacks (not substacks, but different individual stacks), with one stack acting as the "library" (with the magic code: start using stack "s1").

I wanted to pass some data from the library stack (e.g. stack "s1") to another stack (e.g. stack "s2"), and place the data on s2's datagrid form.
My problem is that it works well when testing on desktop, before it is built; once it is built as a standalone Android app, the data could not be displayed properly on the datagrid on the mobile device.

From stack s1 (mobile view):

[image]

After passing data to stack s2 it looks like this (mobile view):

[image]

*Notice that I have also included a list field on s2, which displays the data correctly.

Really appreciate it if anyone can point out what is the cause of the issue, and what can be done to display data correctly on datagrid passed from another stack...
Thank you!

P.S. I'm using LiveCode 7.0.1 to build the app

Comment: Why are you using several stacks instead of a main-stack with substacks? It is hard to tell from your images what is wrong. Are you sure you have included all your stacks in the stand-alone? Are all your stacks including the datagrid substack? This might be a problem when using several different stacks instead of a main-stack and substacks to main as the datagrid includes a substack. Mobile apps are by default single window apps and you need to ensure that they all go fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file in **specialfolderPath("documents")** to share data.